How can I draw a wedge of a cylinder?
Following the question on TeX StackExchange

I want to get this picture

I tried
Clear["Global`*"]
myangle = Pi/4;
myr = 4;
myh = myr* Tan[myangle];
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
mycylinder = Cylinder[{pO, pA}, myh];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{myr, 0, 0}, {-myr, 0, 0}, {0, myr, myh}}];
plot3d = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[mycylinder, plane],
    BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   Boxed -> False];
Show[plot3d, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], mycylinder, Thick, Blue, 
   Line[{{0, myr, 0}, {0, myr, myh}}]}, Boxed -> False] ]
Show[plot3d, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], Thick, Blue, 
   Line[{{0, myr, 0}, {0, myr, myh}}]}, Boxed -> False] ]

and get



Method-1

We plot the plane z==Tan[π/4] x and cut it by the half disk and filling to the bottom.

Reply to comment: To make the boundary smooth, we set AccuracyGoal -> 5 in BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.


Clear[plot,arrow,text];
plot = Plot3D[
   Tan[π/4] x, {x, y} ∈ 
    BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-(π/2), π/2}],
      AccuracyGoal -> 5], BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, Filling -> Bottom, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{LightRed, Opacity[.5]}, 
   FillingStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Green}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, y], 
   Mesh -> {{{0, Directive@{Blue, Thick}}}}];
arrow = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.03], White, 
    Arrow@Table[
      RotationTransform[t, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]@{.35, 0, 0}, {t, 
       Subdivide[0, π/4, 80]}]}];
text = Graphics3D[{Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
    Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
    Text[Style["θ", FontFamily -> "Times", 25, White], {.4, 
      0, .2}]}];
Show[text, arrow, plot, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.3, -2.9, 1.3}]



This method can also calculate the volume.

Integrate[
 Tan[π/4] x, {x, y} ∈ 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {-(π/2), π/2}]]


2/3.

Method-2

Before I post the previous answer,I also test the HalfSpace,but it need to set the plotrange and the effect in Graphics3D not so good. Finally I found ConicHullRegion work perfect.
Update later.

θ1 = 0;
θ2 = π/4;
reg = RegionIntersection[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Cylinder[], AccuracyGoal -> 5], 
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    ConicHullRegion[{0, 0, 
      0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, {{1, 0, Tan[θ1]}, {1, 0, 
       Tan[θ2]}}]]];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Directive@{Opacity[.5], LightRed}], 
  reg},ViewPoint -> {-1.3, -2.9, 1.3}]



If we want to the exact value of the Volume,we should remove the BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.

RegionIntersection[Cylinder[], 
  ConicHullRegion[{0, 0, 
    0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, {{1, 0, Tan[θ1]}, {1, 0, 
     Tan[θ2]}}]] // Volume


2/3.


When θ1 = π/6;θ2 = π/4;



How can I make green parabol smooth?

I use Volume[reg]. How can I get exact result?

@cvgmt just a minor point re: volume: should radius of disk be 2 and hence volume 16/3

@ubpdqn  Yes.  RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}, 2],    ConicHullRegion[{0, 0,      0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, {{1, 0, Tan[0]}, {1, 0,       Tan[π/4]}}]] // Volume  or Integrate[  Tan[π/4] x, {x, y} ∈    Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {-(π/2), π/2}]]

Try Halfspace as follows
reg = HalfSpace[-{0, Sin[myangle], -Cos[myangle] }, 0] (* region under the intersection plane*)

 Region[ RegionIntersection[mycylinder, reg  ],PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {0, 4}}]



If just want surface of region:
ParametricPlot3D[{{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 2 s Cos[t]}, {2 s Cos[t], 
   2 Sin[t], 2 s Cos[t]}, {2 s Cos[t], 2 s Sin[t], 0}}, {t, -Pi/2, 
  Pi/2}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> LightBlue, Mesh -> None]
pp[a_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 
    2 s Cos[t] Tan[a]}, {2 s Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 
    2 s Cos[t] Tan[a]}, {2 s Cos[t], 2 s Sin[t], 0}}, {t, -Pi/2, 
   Pi/2}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> LightBlue, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 8}}]
Manipulate[pp[a], {a, {Pi/6, Pi/4, Pi/3, Pi/2.5}}]


The manipulate gif is here.
ir = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 4, 0 <= z <= x}, {x, y, z}];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 2 Cos[t]}, {t, -Pi/2, 
   Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}], 
 RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 200, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
Volume[ir]
Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] ir]


